# Grails gdoc editor support (esp IntelliJ)

Tags: vim, grails, intellij-idea, gedit, textile

Since Grails 1.2 there's a documentation engine included: [gdoc](http://www.grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Command%20Line/doc.html). The [documentation's syntax](http://docs.codehaus.org/renderer/notationhelp.action) is based on the [Textile format](http://textile.thresholdstate.com/).

Is there some editor support for this? My first choice would be a plugin for IntelliJ, second option on for vim or gedit. Any hints welcome. I am totally a aware that the format is very simple by itself but having code coloring and content assist would be really nice.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about Intellij, since many of us work on Macs we tend to use TextMate which has an excellent Textile plugin with completion, preview etc.

Comment: thanks for that statement, but I'm on Linux, so no Textmate. In the meantime I found http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2305 for vim.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is almost 3 years old, but just in case... I found that the Mylyn Wikitext plugin was useful for this in Eclipse.  Just had to add the .gdoc file extension to it in under the properties.